# foreach loop to fetch JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to make this json

```
{"date":"04\/24\/2018"},
{"date":"04\/25\/2018"}
```

print the values as follows

```
['04/24/2018', '04/25/2018']
```

But I could not do it, any suggestions?

```js
var datesBooking = [
{"date":"04\/24\/2018"},
{"date":"04\/25\/2018"}
];

for(var key in datesBooking){
  console.log(datesBooking[key])
}
```

Comment: `datesBooking.map(x => x.date)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are explicitly looking for the `foreach` method:

```js
var datesBooking = [
  {"date": "04\/24\/2018"},
  {"date": "04\/25\/2018"}
];

datesBooking.forEach(function(data, index) {
  datesBooking[index] = data.date;
});

console.log(datesBooking);
```

**The above code will rewrite over the existing array.**

The same can be achieved using `map`

```js
var datesBooking = [
  {"date": "04\/24\/2018"},
  {"date": "04\/25\/2018"}
];

datesBooking = datesBooking.map(x => x.date);

console.log(datesBooking);
```

As you can see, the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) was introduced to simplify such a use of `foreach`.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `map` method by passing a provided **callback** function.

```js
var datesBooking = [
{"date":"04\/24\/2018"},
{"date":"04\/25\/2018"}
];
console.log(datesBooking.map(function(item){
  return item.date;
}));
```

Another approach is simply using `arrow` functions.

```
datesBooking.map(a => a.date)
```